# Minified all images - Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I have more than 100 images in my `images/` folder.

## Here is my imagemin - Grunt Config

```
// The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
      src: '{,*/*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,ico}',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
}
```

---

When I run `grunt build` I saw this

```
Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
Minified 7 images (saved 492.79 kB)
```

Only 7 of my images got minified. Not all.
I've tried changing the `*` around in a diff combination, but so far - no luck.

---

`src: '{,*/*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,ico}'`

How do I fix my `src` to minified **everything** in my images folder ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be in the `src` [globbing pattern](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). The pattern you are using only matches those images that are in the `cwd` root or in a two levels deep ones (`{,*/*/}`).

If you want all the images in the `cwd` directory to be minified regardless the levels of subdirectories they reside, you should use the `**/*` globbing pattern instead:

```
imagemin: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
      src: '**/*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,ico}',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank-you very much. I'm trying your code right now.

Comment: I got this error `"Warning: Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
    Warning: Error: Command failed: /Users/bunlong/Desktop/yeoman project/yo/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/vendor/optipng -strip all -quiet -clobber -o 3 -out /var/folders/54/y_678c6n7q7_pgk1v5lkzwnr0000gp/T/4a47ee72-0c86-4ef8-bf37-876b37850777 /var/folders/54/y_678c6n7q7_pgk1v5lkzwnr0000gp/T/df5a73eb-8d62-431d-926f-7a1e9f5b9084
     in file app/images/overlays/02.png Use --force to continue.
    
    Aborted due to warnings."`

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the `optipng` command. There is an open issue in the grunt-contrib-imagemin repo that describes the same behavior https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin/issues/290. Someone proposes updating imagemin to latest version but... not sure if it really solves the issue.